# How are template tags for components generated in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I was tasked with adding some new features to an old system built with AngularJS. I'm a backend developer so I don't know js frameworks in deep but I have mostly figured out how Angular JS works, however I'm stuck with some html templates in components. The documentation shows an identical example of what I'm facing.

In a file called `index.js` I have

```
angular.module('heroApp', []).controller('MainCtrl', function MainCtrl() {
  this.hero = {
    name: 'Spawn'
  };
});
```

I have another file called `heroDetail.js` containing

```
angular.module('heroApp').component('heroDetail', {
  templateUrl: 'heroDetail.html',
  bindings: {
    hero: '='
  }
});
```

An html file called `index.html`

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
  <b>Hero</b><br>
  <hero-detail hero="ctrl.hero"></hero-detail>
</div>
```

And finally a file called `heroDetail.html`

```
<span>Name: {{$ctrl.hero.name}}</span>
```

My question is, how is the `<hero-detail></hero-detail>` tag generated? There seems to be no definition for it in the files nor in the entire project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here:

```
.component('heroDetail'
```

lower camel case goes to kebab case for the tag.

for example `.component('myHeroDetail'` would result in `<my-hero-detail>`

One of the many weird quirks of angularjs that was improved upon in angular 2.